# ng-click is not working in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

when we click any list element i need to change the scope value and also trigger onclick function.

But in this code ng-click is not working when we added for label for  list element.

Code is below,

```
<ul class="" id="filter" path="filter">
<li value="popular" id="popular" data-faculty="Popular" class="item" onclick="SortByFilter(this, 'smartphone');" ng-click="Mobilebidirectionalsort = !Mobilebidirectionalsort"><label for="Popular">Popular</label><span class="btnSort"><input type="radio" id="Popular" name="filterOptions" class="btnRadio"></span></li>

<li value="newest" id="newest" data-faculty="High Rating" class="item" onclick="SortByFilter(this, 'smartphone');" ng-click="Mobilebidirectionalsort = !Mobilebidirectionalsort"><label for="High Rating">High Rating</label><span class="btnSort"><input type="radio" id="High Rating" name="filterOptions" class="btnRadio"></span></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Why have the onclick in your code? You must you only ng-click in the angular application.

Comment: Try using anchor tag to your list

Comment: onclick and ng-click is working fine without adding label tag in list tag . Any other specific reason ?

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with this code;  your problem must be something caused by code that you haven't listed here.  please update the question with a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working fine. I've created a mirror of the situation that you've described above and you can clearly see how `ng-click` is changing value of `Mobilebidirectionalsort`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="col-sm-7 nopadding doc-att">
        Mobilebidirectionalsort value : {{Mobilebidirectionalsort}}
        <ul class="" id="filter" path="filter">
            <li value="popular" id="popular" data-faculty="Popular" class="item" onclick="SortByFilter(this, 'smartphone');" ng-click="Mobilebidirectionalsort = !Mobilebidirectionalsort">
                <label for="Popular">Popular</label><span class="btnSort"><input type="radio" id="Popular" name="filterOptions" class="btnRadio"></span>
            </li>
            <li value="newest" id="newest" data-faculty="High Rating" class="item" onclick="SortByFilter(this, 'smartphone');" ng-click="Mobilebidirectionalsort = !Mobilebidirectionalsort">
                <label for="High Rating">High Rating</label><span class="btnSort"><input type="radio" id="High Rating" name="filterOptions" class="btnRadio"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

            myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.Mobilebidirectionalsort = true;

            }]);


            function SortByFilter(attr1, attr2) {
                console.log('SortByFilter called');
            }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @CodeMan It's exactly the same code as your's. I haven't tempered anything. If there's any problem, then it would be in your controller. You need to post your complete code.